# Bazel docker_image copy extra folder

Tags: go, bazel, bazel-rules

I am currently using bazel for my GoLang app.

```
container_image(
     name = "my-golang-app",
     base = "@ubuntu_base//image",
     cmd = ["/bin/my-golang-app"],
     directory = "/bin/",
     files = [":my-golang-app"],
     tags = [
         "manual",
         VERSION,
     ],
     visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
 )
```

Except my-golang-app folder I need to copy, while building this image, another folder named my-new-folder and everything in it.

How does one do that with bazel? I can't seem to find the solution in the bazel docs.

```
dockerfile {
             run 'mkdir -p /usr/local/bin'
             // add the lines below
             add {
                 from 'docker/my-new-folder/'
                 into '/'
             }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pkg_tar`](https://bazelbuild.github.io/rules_pkg/latest.html#pkg_tar) like the [container_image docs](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker#container_image) reference. Something like this:

```py
pkg_tar(
    name = "my-files",
    srcs = glob(["my-new-folder/**"]),
    strip_prefix = ".",
)

container_image(
    name = "my-golang-app",
    files = [":my-golang-app"],
    <everything else you already have>,
    tars = [":my-files"],
)
```

`pkg_tar` has various options to control where your files end up, if you want something beyond just taking an entire directory. For more complicated arrangements, I find multiple `pkg_tar` rules for various directories linked together via `deps` a helpful pattern.

Comment: Yep took me a few hours but found that pkg_tar thingy. I confirm it is the right answer

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the files end up on the image and what the options are for those of use that don't have a PHD in Bazel? The link for `pkg_tar` is dead and I can find no decent docs anywhere.

Comment: I updated the `pkg_tar` link. The other `rules_pkg` rules on that page have various other options. They also have [some examples[(https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_pkg/tree/main/examples).